# django-hitcount - display the date and ip of each recorded "hit"

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

This is a noob question, so excuse the lack of understanding.

I'm using python 3.6 & django 1.10.5.

I've been given a test page that now uses [django-hitcount](https://django-hitcount.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html) to track the number of times a document is "hit" - viewed and downloaded. This seems to be working OK.

I now want to extend the code so that I can display the date and ip of each time the document is "hit".

I've looked at the db tables and the date and ip is stored in the django-hitcount tables as shown below:

[image]

Here's the views.py code to display the recorded hitcount "hits":

```
from hitcount.models import HitCount
....
document_hits = HitCount.objects.filter(
    content_type=content_type, modified__gte=one_week_ago).order_by('object_pk')
```

I've read the [django-hitcount docs](https://django-hitcount.readthedocs.io/), however I am unable to understand how to write/extend the view to display the date and ip of each hit.

I've tried many things, but I'm missing something fundamental here.

Any assistance to steer me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By looking into the [django-hitcount documentation on displaying](https://django-hitcount.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#displaying-hits) and the [django-hitcount github models.py](https://github.com/thornomad/django-hitcount/blob/master/hitcount/models.py) we observe that there is a `class Hit` that has a `ForeignKey` to `class HitCount`, with a default reverse relation of the name `hits`, hence we can deduct that the way to display such information as the date and IP of each hit would be by adding into the project the following:

A view:

```
from hitcount.views import HitCountDetailView

class YourModelCountHitDetailView(HitCountDetailView):
    model = YourModel        # your model goes here
    count_hit = True    # set to True if you want it to try and count the hit
```

and a template:

```
{% for hit in hitcount.hits %}
    {{ hit.ip }}<br/>
    {{ hit.created }}
{% endfor %}
```